# getting ORA04091- table is mutating error while working with JDBC ,spring framework and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, triggers, spring-jdbc

I  want to insert multiple rows in one go with oracle database.
I am using spring framework. While using executeBatch();
I am getting the error as ORA-04091: table FEED_IMPL is mutating trigger /function may not see it.

Here is FeedManager.java code :

```
   //source for DataToInsert comes from a rowMapper class
    //for simplicity I am showing few of the data which is there in List<feedData>
    List<feedData> DataToInsert = [feedData(id =12,source_name =SYD,file_name=syd_210911.json),feedData(id =12,source_name =SYD,file_name=syd_210912.json),feedData(id =12,source_name =SYD,file_name=syd_210913.json)]
 int count =0;
//myJDBCtemplate bean created in dbConfig
    DataSource ds= myJDBCtemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource();
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    final int batchSize = 200;
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    for(feedData insertData: DataToInsert ) {
    ps.setInt(1,insertData.getId());//Id from DataToInsert 
    ps.setString(2,insertData.getSource());//source_name from DataToInsert 
    ps.setString(3,insertData.getFileName());//file_name from DataToInsert 
    ps.addBatch();
if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
ps.executeBatch();
}    
} 
    int[]affectedRows = ps.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
```

**Query used:**
INSERT INTO FEED_IMPL(ID,SOURCE_NAME,FILE_NAME)VALUES(?,?,?)

I want to have 200+ rows of inserts into database at a time, for question's simplicity I have shown data of 3 rows only inside `DataToInsert` List.

Error I am getting here

> table FEED_IMPL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512
> : at "FEED_IMPL_NEW_VERSION_TRG", line 5 ORA-04088: error during
> execution of trigger 'FEED_IMPL_NEW_VERSION_TRG'

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` statement is a *victim* here. Problem is somewhere in the database trigger (named `feed_impl_new_version_trg`) created on the `feed_impl` table.

Usually, it is about the fact that you're modifying the table (inserting into it, right?), while trigger tries to read the same table (i.e. contains `select ... from feed_impl`). That's called "mutating".

There are several options:

- maybe you don't need a trigger at all
- maybe trigger is *poorly* written and can be fixed
- if not, there's still a workaround using

  - a compound trigger, or
  - a package

Can't tell anything else as I don't know what that trigger does.